# How can i use a global variable in ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can i use a global variable in my function? this is my whole script, i dont want to use class, only i would like to use my variable `h` in my `func1`

```
h = {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}
total = h.values.sum

def func1 ()
    h.each do |key, value|
        puts "#{key}"
    end
    
    puts h.keys.count
end


func1()
```

i am getting this error:

```
`func1': undefined local variable or method `h' for main:Object (NameError)
```

what is the wrong?

Comment: There are no "JSON objects" in ruby. The code above would return you a ruby hash. You can create those directly, without needing to parse a string.

Comment: Note that while Ruby has the commonly-used object `nil` (an instance of [NilClass](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/NilClass.html)) it does not have `null`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland But JSON does have `null` so `'{"e":null}'` as a string of JSON would be `{'e' => nil}` in Ruby.

Comment: You could say `config = {RS: 9, TI: 2}` in Ruby to create a `config` hash (roughly equivalent to an object in JavaScript). Then say `config[:RS]` and `config[:TI]` to access the values.

Comment: @mu, thanks, LSNED.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks, I just had to LSNED LSNED ;)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the way i created the json is ok?

Comment: Just to be a bit picky: those in javascript are javascript objects - NOT json objects. Actually. there's no such a thing as json object at all. JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation" and is a data interchange format - so it's merely a representation of the object, similarly to yaml or xml

Comment: You changed your question from _"How can i create a json object"_ to _"How can i use a global variable"_. It’s fine to revise a question, but those are two completely different topics.

Comment: Your question is unclear. There are no global variables in your code. What global variables are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use your *local* variable (it is not a global variable) in your method then you have to pass it to your questions, for example, like this:

```
h = { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }

def func1(hash)
  hash.each do |key, value|
    puts "#{key}"
  end
    
  puts hash.keys.count
end

func1(h)
#=> foo
    bar
    baz
    3
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in @spickermann's answer, passing local variables to methods is the best way to do things, but if you actually want to create a global (*use extreme discretion*), you use a `$` on the variable name.

```
$h = {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}

def func1
    $h.each do |key, value|
        puts "#{key}"
    end
    
    puts $h.keys.count
end

func1
```